# How to know that a macbook pro box has never been opened ?

Tags: macbook-pro

How to know that a macbook pro box has never been opened ? Is it all about the plastic stuff or there is some sort of sealing there ?

Answer (score 2):

MacBook, MacBook Air & MacBook Pro boxes are sealed with shrink wrap. Inside, the machine has a clear plastic sleeve with an Apple license sticker which has a perforated strip which is intended to be broken. However you can open this sleeve from the side leaving the sticker intact.

Answer (score 1):

Not definitive for a MacBook- but a new iMac I opened only last week had an irreplaceable tear strip across the box lid. Removing it leaves two clean edged white strips still stuck to either side of the opening.